# Why do I need to inject the controllers I want in my app?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the source code for an app which reads as follows:

```
angular.module('graffio', [
  'graffio.signupController',
  'graffio.loginController',
  'graffio.mainController',
  'ui.router'
])
```

I have quite a few questions! So much confusion...

1. How is code loading these controllers which are defined later in the
   code?
2. Why do I even need to state which controllers I want in my
   app? Why can't I just have all the ones I declare?
3. Why does the angular documentation use the word 'injectable' so much? Isn't
   injectable just the same as require?

Comment: 3. Nope, injectable has nothing to do with require.  All I can say is work through some examples and it will eventually become clear.  Maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Angular, you can group as much or as little code into a module as you like. And you can compose modules together, like the author of the app you are looking at has done. The final module will have all of the services, config blocks, routes, controllers, directives, filters and so on that are in all of the modules it depends on as well as its own module.

This author has chosen to put each controller into its own module. Which is why the main module needs to depend on each of those modules. In my opinion, this seems like overkill, but it is what has been done, and all you need to do is understand it, not agree with it.

In answer to your other questions:

#### How is code loading these controllers which are defined later in the code?

When your code first runs, all the modules will be declared, and populated with directives, routes, controllers, services and so on. Nothing gets used yet. So long as when the code you have above is run, the other modules have already been declared then everything is fine (this may be done by a build process such as a Grunt task).

Then, when the `document.ready` event occurs, Angular looks through your HTML for an `ng-app` directive that says which module to load as your application. It then does what it calls the "bootstrap" process for that module.

#### Why do I even need to state which controllers I want in my app? Why can't I just have all the ones I declare?

Because this author has put each controller in their own module. If you put all the controllers you want into one module, then you don't need to declare them like that.

#### Why does the angular documentation use the word 'injectable' so much? Isn't injectable just the same as require?

Sort of. It is similar in that you are asking for a dependency by name and then using it.

It is different in that with `require` you can't typically modify what value is retrieved for a given dependency at runtime. With dependency injection, you can swap or modify dependencies at run time if you so choose (before your app starts properly and the dependencies are injected into the code using them).

This is perfect for testing, so that you can use a mock (fake) version of a dependency for testing purposes, instead of using the normal version. Think of a service that makes a call to get some data from the server and returns a promise. You can just create a mock version of that service that doesn't call to the server, just returns some test data immediately. This makes your unit tests fast, and means you don't need to be running your web server for them to work.